# What is the proper way to write the complementary of this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set

$$A = \left \{ 1 - \frac{1}{n}:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash \{ 0 \} \right\} \cup [1, 2]$$

What is the proper way to write $A^c$? (The universe set is $\mathbb{R}$). I thought that basically

$$A = B \cup C$$ hence $$A^c = B^c \cap C^c = \mathbb{R}\backslash A$$

Now $C^c = (-\infty, 1) \cup (2, \infty)$ but I cannot figure out what is $B^c$.

Is it by chance $$B^c = \left\{\mathbb{R}\backslash\left\{1 - \frac{1}{n}:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: I guess this depends on what you call "proper". As long as you understand what the complement is, it is up to you how to describe it. What you write for $C^c$ and $B^c$ is correct. Note that what you write in $B^c$ is just the definition of complement.

Comment: @Thank you! Anyway, I proved the set is closed, because it does contain all its limit points. I'm stuck in understanding if it's also open, because I cannot figure out well what is the complementary. On the other side, I know that the only two set both closed and open in $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}$ itself and the void so...

Comment: You did write the complement correctly. I am not sure what results or definitions you are using, but maybe you want to check directly that it is not open by showing that for some point $x\in A$, there is no interval such that $x\in(a,b)\subset A$.